# Setting WPF Image's source from a Window icon (.ico)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, icons

I have set my WPF Window icon as below:

```
<Window Icon="icon3.ico">
  <Grid>
    <Image x:Name="img"></Image>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now I am tring to set programmatically an WPF image's source with WPF Window icon:

```
this.img.Source = this.Icon as BitmapImage;
```

but this.img.Source is null after setting it. Why?

Comment: `img.Source = Icon;` is all you need to write.

Comment: The `as` operation will result in `null` if the conversion does not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just

```
img.Source = Icon;
```

Maybe Icon isn't a BitmapImage type... either way, Icon is an ImageSource and the Source property on img is an ImageSource. You can just assign it directly always.

Comment: Ooooppsss I didn't think it. Just assign it directly works! Thanks!

Comment: @Clemens  Hey man, I appreciate the edit but it was an unnecessary edit.  Please refrain from using your super powers unless they are truly needed.  I've been here long enough to work this site for better or worse.  If there was a spelling mistake or something just wrong then I understand but I prefer my posts to be read the way I spoke them.  Thank you.

Comment: There's no `Icon.Source`, it's just `img.Source = Icon;`

Comment: @Clemens Ok, I'll give you that.  I thought I had just Icon in the first post... The other edits though were overkill.